# With Indian e-visa, can I do 2nd entry from Nepal back to India through Banbasa border crossing?

Tags: india, e-visas, nepal

My situation is that I'm already in India. I entered India with tourist e-visa. First entry has to be through one of designated air/sea ports. I did enter through Delhi airport and I got visa stamp to my czech passport. Stamp says I have multiple entries, 90 days continuous stay in India and visa is valid for 1 year. Now I used up almost 90 days and I want to travel to Nepal for shortest time possible and return to India to get another 90 days of continuos stay. I'm in Rishikesh so closest and most cheap option seems to be by bus traveling to Banbasa (land) boarder crossing. Can I return back on my e-visa also through Banbasa (which is not designated 1st entry port)? And how long do I need to stay in Nepal?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible with e-visa to travel out and back in to India through Banbasa border crossing. I just tried today :). But you can not return same day (as I wanted). You need to stay in Nepal for 1 night and return next day. You need to pay 2400 Inr at Nepali border and they give you 15 days Nepali Visa. They also need 1 passport photo.[image: see my passport stamps]
Basically you shall end up with 4 passport stamps. 1st stamp for leaving India. 2nd stamp for entering Nepal. 3rd stamp for leaving Nepal. 4th stamp for entering India.